# Missing one element of dictionary cause of If statement

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement

i use this code to store items of dictionaries in `doc` variable.
This code works fine but I miss the first element of time because of the if statement.

```
def convert(old):
    time_key = 'Time '
    # Save the time
    time_item = (time_key, old[time_key])
    # Add remove it
    del old[time_key]
    # Copy remaining items to new dicts and save them in a list
    return [dict([time_item, item]) for item in old.items()]

row = {
    'Time ': '2017-12-01T13:54:04', 
    'Energy [kWh]': '0.01', 
    'Voltage [V]': '221.64', 
    'Current [A]': '0.08',
}

new_data = convert(row)
#print(new_data)
Zeitvalue= ""
Device=""
Value=""
for d in new_data:
    #print(d)
    for key, value in d.items():
        if key == 'Time ':
            Zeitvalue = value
            #print(value)
            continue
        else:
            Device = key
            Value = value
        doc = {'Time ':Zeitvalue,'Device':Device, 'Measure':Value} 
        print("This is doc variable:",doc) # doc vaiable with missed time element
```

SO when i print doc i got this 
**Output:**

```
doc:     {'Device': 'Voltage [V]', 'Measure': '221.64', 'Time ': ''} # **ISSUE: variable time is missed here, How to fix it ?**
   doc:     {'Device': 'Current [A]', 'Measure': '0.08', 'Time ': '2017-12-01T13:54:04'}
   doc:     {'Device': 'Energy [kWh]', 'Measure': '0.01', 'Time ': '2017-12-01T13:54:04'}
```

Comment: Please uncomment the printing lines responsible for the output.

Comment: It's possible because of the "continue" statement

Comment: Remove `continue` from the `if key == 'Time '` condition. Beware, tho, that all other entries will have an inherited `Zeitvalue` so if `Time` does not occur for each set of entries, the next set will have the previous set's time.

Comment: And please do not use Upper Case for variable names!

Comment: you are right. I didn't think about this case. So i removed continue.
 @Igle you ment with upper case if statement?  Which method would you prefer to do the same work?

Comment: `Zeitvalue = value` should be `zeitvalue = value`, `Device = value` should be `device = value` and so on. But only for variable names. The keys of your output dict can stay UpperCase. See [Pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables)

Comment: i got it. thanks for the advice but i think this rule is only significant for funktions to not get in trouble with functions of python's sub library 
´Use the function naming rules: lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.´

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the below changes in the code. Remove continue statement. Also assign value to doc after the inner loop for dictionary is over as you need all three values.

```
for d in new_data:
#print(d)
    for key, value in d.items():
        if key == 'Time ':
            Zeitvalue = value
            #print(value)

        else:
            Device = key
            Value = value

    doc = {'Time ':Zeitvalue,'Device':Device, 'Measure':Value} 
    print(doc)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are just setting values then place the doc assignment outside the for loop

```
for d in new_data:

    for key, value in d.items():
        if key == 'Time ':
            Zeitvalue = value
            continue
        else:
            Device = key
            Value = value
    doc = {'Time ':Zeitvalue,'Device':Device, 'Measure':Value}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have problem in this line:

`doc = {'Time ':Zeitvalue,'Device':Device, 'Measure':Value}` when you use it inside the for loop! , each iteration overrides the previous assignment, furthermore - you cause unexpected behavior , since dictionary is not order data structure - meaning : if you encountered "tine" key first - it will work fine , but if you did not encountered 'time' first - the value of it is still == "" , since you initiate it to that value and you did not updated it since.

move the `doc = {'Time ':Zeitvalue,'Device':Device, 'Measure':Value}` to the outer loop , and not the one going over each key and value and you will be fine.